# In System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox, how to convert from LineNumber to character position?

Tags: .net, winforms, richtextbox

I would like the converse of [RichTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex(VS.85).aspx)

I have a line number and I want to retrieve the char index for that line. 
The method might be called `RichTextBox.GetCharIndexFromLine()`.

Is it possible, simply?

Comment: first character of that line Index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(int lineNumber)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the method is RichTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(LineNumber)